# Working with TCP sockets in Python

Tags: python, xml, sockets, server, tcp

I need to:

1) Create a socket to a specific IP and Port

2) Send a string of data via the connection

3) Await the response and check it is valid

I have seen a lot of conflicting advice at the moment and so decided to ask a new question to try and clear this up.

I'm trying to use the `socket` library in Python to achieve this however am facing a couple of issues. I've tried a few different methods, however I am facing an issue sending the string of data. **My data is in XML format so getting this as a string is proving difficult for me**. I have attempted converting it to binary however would prefer it in plain text format, just that it should be as a string. Any pointers as to **whether the code would fulfil the 3 steps I wish to complete would be perfect!**

```
import socket
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect(('109.73.xxx.xxx', 29006))
s.sendall('*XML SHOULD GO HERE*')
data = s.recv(1024)
s.close()
print 'Received', repr(data)
```

I haven't got a response back from the server at the moment because I suspect of the erroneous format of the string of data sent. This means I haven't been able to check whether the code prints the response data from the server.

**The XML data I need to pass as a string** is in the following format:

```
<Message xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/CANNOTPROVIDETHISURL" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/CANNOTPROVIDETHISURL">
  <ClientHeader>
    <element1>RC1234</element1>
    <element2>1234</element2>
    <element3>12345678</element3>
    <element4>123456789</element4>
    <element5>-1</element5>
    <element6>-1</element6>
    <element7>A123</element7>
    <element8>TMS</element8>
  </ClientHeader>
  <MsgType>TYPE</MsgType>
  <MsgData></MsgData>
</Message>
```

Comment: At first you have to wait for an response. If you try to read the socket immediately it will yield no data since there is nothing yet.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21446899/python-socket-wait might also be useful info.

Comment: Capture network packets with wireshark to see the tcp exchange.

Comment: Calling `recv` by default *will* wait on data to be returned by the server. You need do nothing to make that happen. More specifically, `recv` will block until the first byte of payload is returned by the server *or* the server closes its end of the connection, whichever happens first. (Also note that you *might* need to call `recv` more than once to get the entire response, depending on its size and other factors. But that doesn't seem to be a factor here.)

Comment: In python2, you should be able to send that XML block directly as a string. I would explore logs on the server to find out what's going wrong. Possibly the server is expecting something more: an additional CR-LF at the end maybe?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. As @GilHamilton has said, the `recv` command included an implicit wait. I am using Python2.7 so I've now used the three quotation marks like so """XML DATA""" which has enabled my data to be passed as a string. The problem I'm facing now is `socket.error: [Errno 10054] An exisiting connection was forcibly closed by the remote host`. This is probably due to the actual payload of the string, so I'll have a tinker and see what's happening using WireShark. I'll feedback what I have found.

Comment: FEEDBACK: Socket is functioning perfectly with the addition of a STX to introduce the message and ETX to close the string. However, as I'm running the python script (.py file) using Robot Framework as it's part of an automation script, **is there a way to use certain elements from the XML response text as inputs for the next string of data?**

Comment: Yes. Whole different question though. Python has several options for parsing XML: https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/xml.html?highlight=xml#module-xml