# Python update prompt from response from server

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a program that prints a prompt and accepts input.

```
while True:
    my_prompt = '> '

    in_data = input(my_prompt)

    process_input(in_data)
```

When I enter a certain command, it will send a packet to a server. The server will check if the conditions are valid and then send a response. If the condition is met, it will send a value which I want the prompt to be updated.

```
data = recv(1024)
my_prompt = data
```

The issue I am running into is the `while loop` will return faster than the command can be sent and a response can get back. So if I enter the command, the prompt will rotate back and print the old prompt again. Then I will get a response from the server which tells me to update the prompt. But I have to push enter before the prompt gets updated.

```
>: [ENTER PUSHED]
>: my_command
>: (at this point, the packet was sent and a response was received)[ENTER PUSHED]
new_prompt:
```

So as you can see, the prompt will loop back again and show me the old prompt because it was printed before the server sent me back a response. And then when I push enter, it recognizes the prompt changed and prints the new prompt.

Is it possible to get past this?

EDIT:

More stuff happens before the prompt. Such as connecting to the server and creating a thread that receives.

So basically the prompt accepts from the user something. Then it is sent to the server and comes back to prompt. Whenever the server gets done processing what was received and sends a response back, the main application receives it and updates prompt. But the prompt is already printed back out before it gets this reply so the prompt is not updated.

```
def process_input(data):
    sock.send(data)
```

Comment: What exactly does `process_input` do? If this statement was blocking, the loop would restart after it finishes

Comment: ```process_input``` sends the input to the server. So it doesn't block and quickly returns.

Comment: If you posted the function here that would help

Comment: Added more to it.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21446899/python-socket-wait/21447574

Comment: That doesn't help.